# Do transmission lines induce electric or magnetic fields in towers?

Tags: inductance, transmission-line

Transmission lines have EM fields around them due to the high amount of current. Do these fields affect transmission towers (metal or otherwise)? If so, would it be possible to estimate the current flowing through the lines by measuring EM fields at the base of a transmission tower?

Comment: They also have EM fields because of the high voltage. It would be difficult to separate the voltage effects from the current effects at the base of the tower.

Answer (score 2):

> Do these fields affect transmission towers?

To some extent.

1. You have electric field simply because of the voltage on the wire. This static electricity has an effect on nearby objects. Air ionization, attraction forces, etc.
2. The magnetic field induces currents (and voltages) in conductive structures. BUT, the effect on towers will be minimal simply because *power lines and comms towers are perpendicular to each other.* So pretty much no inductive interaction comes into play.

What's more, such structures are always grounded. So there's no voltage on them. The only thing you may be able to detect on the tower is its magnetic field originating from the 50Hz current flowing up and down the structure. However I said this current will be minimal, so yeah.

If you'd be able to *measure* currents in power lines from any of that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Transmission lines for power are balanced whether it is single, dual or three phase. This means that any magnetic effect seen at some several metres away will be nearly zero. Current travels down one wire and back up the other, therefore the mag fields tend to cancel at some distance away. This means you can't easily estimate the current flow. The electric fields also tend to cancel but E field has nothing to do with current flow.

Answer (score 1):

I am a geologist, not an engineer.  That said, I inadvertently ran an experiment which is relevant to this thread. I recently had a geophysical survey done under a power line (132 kV three phase 50 Hz).  The image below is a cross-section showing induced polarization of the soil and rock under the power line.  Note the spatial association of highly chargeable zones (red) at a depth of 100-200 m with the towers.  The measured range is 0 - 40 mV/V.  Bear in mind that the spatial resolution gets poor in the last 400 m at both ends of the line so the relationship is not as strong.

The survey uses surface electrodes spaced every 20 m to measure current.  At 40 m intervals, at a distance of 50 m perpendicular to the measurement array, a current pulse is injected and the decay after each pulse is recorded.  Some rocks are more chargeable than others and this is what we are looking for.

My geophysicist does not see 50 Hz spikes in the decay curves so he is convinced these are real rock properties of the anomalous zones.  I'm not a big believer in coincidences when it comes to geology and suspect the 50 Hz frequency is not even relevant here.  This sure looks like there is some sort of field induced in the towers.  Note that the transmission lines themselves do not seem to have an impact.

[image: IP X-section showing influence of power lines near Agadez, Niger]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This is a very interesting answer but it unfortunately does not really answer the question. I suggest you ask a new question (something along the lines of "Do transmission lines induce polarization in the soil and rock beneath the line?") and post this answer as an [answer to your own question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This might seem silly but it is important to keep this site in a question-and-answer format rather than open threads. It will help other users find this information if they have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention transmission lines and EM fields so presumably a question about RF.

Transmission lines are typically Co-axial cables, balanced twin or hollow wave-guides.

The Co-ax and hollow wave guide theoretically have no external fields if made from perfect conductors, some small leakage might exist.  A balanced twin (less common these days) will have an unbalanced near-field and this will cause local effects, for this reason they are separated from surrounding metal structures.

The unbalanced field can be measured (still small) and an SWR meter does just that.  However the amount of power coupled onto a massive tower structure will most likely not give useful measurable values.  Voltages induced on the structure will more likely occur near the radiator (antenna) where the transmission line ends.

Answer (score 0):

I climb these HV towers for telecommunications at the top for work. My knowledge isn't that great with voltage as i have no linesman qualifications but when working about 3-4m away from the lines while not touching the steelwork with my hands directly (in harness) I do get occasional mild shocks when retouching the steel.